# Aspect for custom annotation doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm trying to write the aspect with @Around advice for custom annotation but some why it doesn't call.
Here my code:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectMeasureTime {
    @Around(value = "execution(* com.beh.businesslayer..*(..)) && @annotation(measureTime)")
    public void measureTime(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, MeasureTime measureTime) throws Throwable {
    /*some code*/
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.beh"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = false)
public class WebConfig {
}
```

---

```
package com.beh.businesslayer.businessworkflows.pagefetcher;
public class PageFetcherWriter implements ItemWriter, StepExecutionListener {
    @MeasureTime("timee")
    private void printString(Object s) {
        logger.info("entry = " + s);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.beh.businesslayer.businessworkflows.pagefetcher;
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MeasureTime {
    String value();
}
```

I'm tried make joinpoint without this annotation and it works fine. Tried with @annotation(com.beh.businesslayer.businessworkflows.pagefetcher.MeasureTime) and it also didn't work. Have you any idea why, and how it should look like?

Comment: Are you using AspectJ compile time weaving? Or AspectJ load-time weaving? Or no AspectJ, only Spring AOP?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to pass in a parameter then you need to explicitly tell AspectJ that it is being passsed in

```
@Around(value = "execution(* com.beh.businesslayer..*(..)) && @annotation(measureTime) && args(measureTime)")
public void measureTime(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, MeasureTime measureTime) throws Throwable {
```

Comment: in this way I received Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 multiple bindings0, BindingTypePattern(com.beh.businesslayer.businessworkflows.pagefetcher.MeasureTime, 0),  which probably mean that I should add one more parameter(same annotation interface) to function, but anyway it doesn't work. (

Answer (score 2):

Your advice pointcut expression seems to be good, you don't need to change that.

Spring AOP only works on public methods though, it won't work on your `private void printString(...)` method. You'll need to change it to public.

Spring AOP also doesn't work on arbitrary objects, it only works on objects managed by Spring, i.e. Spring Beans. You'll need to make your `PageFetcherWriter` a spring component by registering it to a spring context. There are many ways to do that, depending on your setup and preferred use case. Annotating it with `@Component` or `@Service` are the most frequent ways to do that. Getting an instance of the managed bean should already have the Spring AOP interceptors applied and your aspect should be working.

**EDIT** Stefano Cazzola found another problem: in your `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, you need to change `proxyTargetClass = false` to `proxyTargetClass = true`.

> Indicate whether subclass-based (CGLIB) proxies are to be created as opposed
>   to standard Java interface-based proxies. The default is `false`.

Comment: I tried with public modifier but it doesn't help, actually I added annotation on the another method of this class and it works(advice executed for that method(write from ItemWriter spring-batch)), but some why it doesn't want to work with "printString" method. Have you any idea why this happened?

Comment: not 100% sure, though Spring might work proxying interfaces, unless explicitly instructed to proxy target classes.

Comment: @Stefano yes, that will be the problem

Comment: @Behemoth it worked if you implemented an interface method, because you had your proxyTargetClass = false, and that only works on interface methods, as pointed out by Stefano Cazzola.